# IcCube Reporting V8 : Multi Header Pivot - Conditional Color expression

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Using IcCube Reporting V8, I want to do conditional colors in the cells of a pivot column, the problem is that I can't identify this column when there are multiple header levels :

In the sample below, I want to identify the column "Interventions/Evolution"
[image]

Picture below shows that $_currentColumn.mdxName$ reports only the 1st row header text "Interventions" even though the current column mentions the complete one "Interventions, 2019":

[image]

How can I catch the complete column name in order to apply conditional colors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Current Column* selection menu in the expression editor sets the `currentColumn` only for the editor (so you can test the expression). The transformation itself runs on all the selected columns where each iteration the `currentColumn` changes.

There are two ways to apply a conditional color transformation to a single column from the table.

- Set the *columns* option of the transformation to only the "Interventions/Evolution" column.
- Set the *columns* option to `All Columns` and use the following expression:

```js
if ("$_currentColumn.caption$".startsWith("Interventions")) {
  return "blue";
}
return "purple";
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. Nevertheless, Way I is not applicable as columns in the widgets can be dynamically defined (due to filters on the report, I may have as columns : "Interv, 2016" ; "Interv, 2017" or as columns "Interv, 2017 ; "Interv, 2018" "Interv, Evolution", so I cannot set the columns option of the transformation to only the "Interv/Evolution" column. Way II is what I use here, the problem is that $_currentColumn.caption$ only returns first part of "real" caption of columns, if column is "Interv, 2019" or "Interv, Evo", it only returns "Interv". It only returns first header part.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce that `$_currentColumn.caption$` returns only the first part. Can you try to hover the column in the result table to see what the caption is? Also, in the screenshot above you use `$_currentColumn.mdxName$`, that will only return the first part.

Comment: What a shame! I was so sure I tested with **$_currentColumn.caption$** when I was using **$_currentColumn.mdxName$**. It works, thank you very much Tom.